# @IBOutlet and @IBAction refers to wrong project, how to get rid of those references?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have copied and pasted some source code from one **old** xcode-project to another **new** project.

Included in the copied code where some @IBOutlets and @IBActions. My intention was to later on hook them up to the storyboard in the new project. *However, xcode somehow managed to copy the references to the old project's storyboard*.  **How can I get rid of those references?**

[image]

**Update**: After having added a connection from my storyboard to the buyButton, xcode indicates that the buyButton is connected to two different storyboards.

[image]

Comment: Is it reproducible after project clean & build? If not, could you please create a minimum project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @Sulthan The references remain after clean and build. I tried to reproduce the issue in a new minimal project, but I could not reproduce the error. So maybe I have done something else with my project.

Comment: take the name of the variable, e.g. "buyButton" and try Xcode search for that name. If there is an outlet connected, you should be able to find it (Xcode searches through xibs and storyboards, too).

Comment: I can only find the "buyButton" in the swift-file. I was expecting to see it in some XML file, but that was not the case.

Answer (score 9):

My current conclusion is that **xcode** (7.3.1) contains a **bug** (or **shortcoming**).

If I terminate xcode and then open my new project then everything looks good.

If I then open the old project, and also open the old storyboard within that project, then the false bullet links becomes visible in my new project.
[image]

My guess is that xcode scans through **all storyboards**, that are currently opened in **any project**, to find a link between an outlet name such as "buyButton" and a storyboard.

Answer (score 6):

For me solved after restarting the Xcode . Now its working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Finally came up with another solution We can also remove connections from Storybord by the following steps:-

[image]

Find Your connection and remove it:-

[image]

Comment: This is still an issue with Xcode 8.3.3 and this solution does not resolve it.  When inspecting the source code, only the correct connection exists.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem. To solve this problem you should (for macOS Catalina 10.15.4, Xcode Version 11.1):

1. Close your project and close Xcode
2. Open `/Users/XXXXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and delete your cache of project
3. Open `/Users/ХХХХХ /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex` and delete all cache from this directory
4. Open your project again and click `Product > Build`

Answer (score 2):

Just Change one letter from name it cause to break relationship to storyboard and link it again to new storyboard, I hope it help you.

Comment: Yes, the link breaks. But when I change the name back it reappears. This means that my new xcode project links to my old project, and I don't want that.

Comment: Why don't you remove all of your link and copy the content then join them again let's see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

Click on the Outlet dot

[image]

click on the Main.Storyboard where it will Lead you

[image]

Click on the View Controller and you'll see Your outlet Connected

[image]

Remove the connection by clicking on the Close button and you're ready to go.

Comment: The problem is thatI don't want to change the storyboard of the old project (I am assuming that the connection is stored in the old storyboard file, but that assumption may be incorrect)

Comment: than go with an underscore dear.

Comment: If your Xcode project is referencing files in another project, you can use File Inspector in the Utilities panel to redirect to the correct location. The steps are: select problem file in Project Navigator, select File Inspector in Utilities panel, see the full path where Xcode *thinks* it is, click on the File Inspector's folder icon to open the 'Select File' dialog, navigate to the correct file in the correct location, and click 'Choose' button.

Answer (score 1):

This is still an issue with Xcode 8.3.3 as of June 25th, 2017.

**The only solution I have been successful with is to change the name of the entity.**

What **doesn't** work for me:

- Clean, clean project build folder
- Restart Xcode
- Upgrade Xcode to newest version (existed in 8.1 and 8.2 for me as well)
- Close the other project that I had open
- Delete and re-add the connection
- Inspect the source code and remove the duplicate connection from the xml
- Click any of the places to view references, delete them, and re-add.